# How to skip splitying if row contains specific string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column which consists state and country name:

```
Name   Region       Value_1 etc.
Apple  Penn State    5641561
Apple  Boston State   21515151
Apple  United States  5545645
etc.
```

and I want to drop string after space (" "), but I want to keep United States as it is.

For example:

```
Name   Region       Value_1 etc.
Apple  Penn          5641561
Apple  Boston         21515151
Apple  United States  5545645
etc.
```

How can I do that? 
i am using following code to split:
`df['Region'] = df['Region'].str.split(' ').str[0]`

Comment: do you want to remove "State" from the string?

Comment: @komatiraju032 yes

Comment: if it contains any string other than "state"?

Comment: @komatiraju032 I only want to remove "State", cells have similar strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace the occurrences of pattern in the series with the replacement string:

```
df['Region'] = df['Region'].str.replace(r'(\sState)\b', '')
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

    Name         Region   Value_1
0  Apple           Penn   5641561
1  Apple         Boston  21515151
2  Apple  United States   5545645
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple'], 'Region': ['Penn State', 'Boston State', 'United States']})
df['Region'] = df['Region'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('State', '') if x.split()[-1].strip() == 'State' else x)
```

**Output:**

```
    Name    Region
0   Apple   Penn
1   Apple   Boston
2   Apple   United States
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using `np.where()`:

```
### Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Name': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple'],
'Region': ['Penn State', 'Boston State', 'United States'],
'Value_1': [5641561, 21515151, 554564]
})

### Using np.where()
df['Region'] = df['Region'].where(df['Region'].str.contains('United States'), 
                            df['Region'].str.split(" ").str[0])

### Output
print(df)

    Name         Region   Value_1
0  Apple           Penn   5641561
1  Apple         Boston  21515151
2  Apple  United States    554564
```